# Listener for panel inside card layout ( which ll be fired every for panel) ???

Tags: extjs4

I have a card layout, Inside card there are many panels inside card items.
I want some listener which will be fired as soon as panel inside card layout is visually activated.
i was trying to achieve the same with Activate and show event,but i am not getting desired output.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to write a controller that references all the views, if you are using the MVC pattern:

```
Ext.define('MyApplication.controller.PanelsController', {
    extend  : 'Ext.app.Controller',
    itemId  : 'panelsController',
    views   : [
        'Panel1',
        'Panel2' // etc...
    ],
    init : function (application) {
        this.control(
            {
                'panel#panel1' : {
                    show   : this.myListener
                 }
            });
    },
    myListener : function () {
        // do stuff here.
    }
});
```